# How can you a optimize stock photography and graphics website without text content for search engines?

Tags: seo, images

I've found lots of SEO articles for blogging based websites. There are also many courses and YouTube videos that cover that.  However, no one teaches how SEO is done for stock photography or graphics template websites.  I can't find information on how Google algorithms work on those websites.

Stock photography and graphics template websites don't contain any content except images and image titles.  There are no paragraphs. Many pages do not have an H1 tag or meta description.  The SEO for these websites is going to have to be completely different from conventional websites.

Can you explain to me how SEO works on such websites?

Comment: Google's algorithm is fully capable of indexing, comparing images and doing image search.  But since no one knows Google's algorithm, the how is hard to determine.  However, if you're just grabbing stock images from somewhere else, it's unlikely you will rank well as Google will probably already have those images in it's system and be able to trace the image back to it's original source.

Comment: Stock photography websites are competing not against blogs but against *each other* in search results, as stock photography isn't something you randomly stumble on, it's something you explicitly look for by searching for instance "stock photos of x". So to any extent SEO issues inherently apply to one stock photo site, they apply to *all* of them, putting them on equal footing. I do believe one of the tricks, though, is to make sure images are properly described through rich alt text, and repeat that alt text visibly on the image's purchase page.